# Discuss using Kotlin Coroutines with MVVM?

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I am using Kotlin Corountines with MVVM pattern and faced a problem: The data processing part is being done inside the ViewModel. While the repository seems not really necessary. When the application needs to call many APIs, the ViewModel will swell. What is everyone's solution to this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The repository is needed, because in the case when you have a large app and gave too much responsibility to the ViewModel it's broke the separation of concerns principle.
Basically in the Andorids [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide) :

> A first idea for implementing the ViewModel might involve directly
> calling the Webservice to fetch the data and assign this data to our
> LiveData object. This design works, but by using it, our app becomes
> more and more difficult to maintain as it grows. It gives too much
> responsibility to the UserProfileViewModel class, which violates the
> separation of concerns principle. Additionally, the scope of a
> ViewModel is tied to an Activity or Fragment lifecycle, which means
> that the data from the Webservice is lost when the associated UI
> object's lifecycle ends. This behavior creates an undesirable user
> experience.
> Instead, our ViewModel delegates the data-fetching process to a new
> module, a repository.

And direct answer for your question:

> Even though the repository module looks unnecessary, it serves an
> important purpose: it abstracts the data sources from the rest of the
> app. Now, our UserProfileViewModel doesn't know how the data is
> fetched, so we can provide the view model with data obtained from
> several different data-fetching implementations.

Basically, you can give all work to your ViewModel, but it's not recommended.

If you work/planning to work as a dev, maintaining your code, make it flexible to change and understandable for others is also important and usually, everyone appreciates this